What is the relation between the first and second inaccessible cardinals?
I know how the first inaccessible transcends the other cardinals by being regular and strong limit but what does a second inaccessible mean.I had two possibilities in mind:
Either:

It is inaccessible in relation to the first inaccessible meaning it transcends the first inaccessible the same way the first inaccessible transcends Aleph0.

It is inaccessible in relation to the cardinals below the first inaccessible meaning it is just the next cardinal after the first inaccessible.
Which is true in this case?



It may be useful to recall the intuition behind the definition of (strongly) inaccessible.  Such a cardinal is intended to transcend everything smaller than itself; it can't be obtained from smaller cardinals by the usual set-theoretic operations (like power set and union). So the second inaccessible $\kappa_2$ not only transcends the first, $\kappa_1$, it transcends everything obtainable by those operations applied to $\kappa_1$, for example, the first $\beth$ fixed point beyond $\kappa_1$, as @spaceisdarkgreen said.

@AndreasBlass Thanks this makes perfect sense. If the first 1-inaccessible is the first fixed point in the enumeration of inaccessibles then what would the first cardinal that is a fixed point of the enumeration of these fixed points be called? Because the first inaccessible is not the first fixed point but has itself many fixed points below it, so what is the equivalent in the inaccessibles hierarchy ?

I think the usual name for an inaccessible $\kappa$ that has $\kappa$ inaccessibles below it is "$2$-inaccessible". But note that such a fixed-point is harder to get than a $\beth$ fixed point. If you let $\kappa_1$ be the first inaccessible and then inductively define $\kappa_{n+1}$ as the $\kappa_n$-th inaccessible, then the supremum of ${\kappa_n:n\in\omega}$ is not inaccessible --- it has cofinality $\omega$.  So you can't just use the inaccessible analog of the iterative process that led to the first $\beth$-fixed point.

A cardinal is inaccessible if it is a regular strong limit cardinal (this is the definition). The "second inaccessible" is just the second least cardinal with these properties, if it exists.
Your first bullet seems accurate, though the statement above is the precise meaning. Your second bullet is not correct. The next cardinal above the first inaccessible is a successor cardinal, so certainly not a strong limit, and therefore not inaccessible.

Let's say K is the least inaccessible cardinal and P the second inaccessible. Then there are P - many cardinals between K and  P that are not inaccessible and not only that but starting from K there are P - many beth fixed points below P. Suppose we are talking about strongly inaccessibles. Is my intuition correct?

@ArianitNitiGashi Yes, that's right. $P$ is the $P$-th cardinal above $K$, the $P$-th strong limit above $K$, the $P$-th beth fixed point above $K$, the $P$-th fixed point of the enumeration of beth fixed points above $K$, and so on.

What would a 1- inaccessible cardinal be? If we enumerate the inaccessibles in increasing order would a 1- inaccessible be the first fixed point of the enumeration?

@ArianitNitiGashi Yes, though there are varying definitions for the inaccessibility hierarchy.

@ArianitNitiGashi See e,g, the blurb on wikipedia

For a very interesting discussion of the size of the least inaccessible cardinal, see the beginning of Section 4.33: More on the Size of the Weakly Inaccessible Cardinals on p. 152 of Basic Set Theory by Azriel Levy (1979; 2002 Dover reprint). Internet Archive copies for borrowing: 1979 edition and 1979 edition. For hierarchies of inaccessibles, read about Maholo cardinals.
